# AngularJS model doesn't update on $state.go

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I have built somewhat of a login and I want the user to be kicked to the dashboard page upon successful login. As of now, everything works as expected except for the model doesn't update until I reload the Dashboard page.

I wrote a service to handle the $http requests:

```
    abcApp.service('Login', function($q, $http){

            return({
                login:login
            })

            var headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' };

            function login(login){
                    var formVals = {
                        username: login.username.$modelValue,
                        password: login.password.$modelValue,
                        remember: login.remember.$modelValue,
                    }
                    var request = $http.post('assets/php/do_login.php', formVals, null, headers);
                    return( request.then( handleSuccess, handleError ) );
            }

            function handleSuccess( response ) {
                 return( response.data );
            }

            function handleError( response ) {
                if (
                    ! angular.isObject( response.data ) ||
                    ! response.data.message
                    ) {
                    return( $q.reject( "An unknown error occurred." ) );
                }

                // Otherwise, use expected error message.
                return( $q.reject( response.data.message ) );

            }

  });
```

Here is the controller that should handle logging in:

```
   $scope.doLogin = function (){
                Login.login($scope.login_form)
                .then(function(data){
                        if(data.status == 'success'){
                            $scope.currentUser = data.user;
                            $scope.msg = 'Welcome '+data.user.realname;
                            $scope.userId = data.user.id;
                            $scope.loggedIn = true;                                 
                        }
                }).then(function () {
                    return $timeout(function () {
                            $state.go(
                                'dashboard', 
                                {},
                                {reload: true}
                            );
                 }, 250);
            });
        };
```

Originally I had this all in a controller, then I split it into a service and controller. I have tried $scope.$apply, but I get an inprog error. How can I get the model to update without reloading?

Answer (score 0):

Your controller and the variables in it will be served from the cache.

There are a few ways you can solve this. First is disable caching in the state definition...

```
$stateProvider.
  state('dashboard', {
    url: '/dashboard',
    cache: false,
```

... but I have had situations where that doesn't work. You can also set a trigger on the state change (either $stateChangeStart on the login controller or $stateChangeSuccess on the dashboard controller):

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
// reload stuff
});
```

You can also set these triggers on the $rootScope if you want them to fire at state changes through all your controllers.